# Strange likelihood construction for information borrowing

Tags: missing-data, likelihood

I recently encountered a strange model while consulting in industry. The goal was to collect information about the parameter of event $A$, say $\theta_A$, but we only observed events $B$ and $C$, which have the same distribution, but with different parameters.
They used "information borrowing", by guessing that $A$ shares more features with $B$ than with $C$. For instance, A is 20% "like" $B$ and 80% "like" $C$. 
Thus, they used the following likelihood for $\theta_A$:
\begin{align}
L( B, C | \theta_A ) &= P( B | \theta_A )^{0.2} \times P( C | \theta_A )^{0.8}\\
\log L( B, C | \theta_A ) &= 0.2 \log P( B | \theta_A ) + 0.8 \log P( C | \theta_A )
\end{align} 
I have never encountered likelihood constructions like this before.
This does make sense, theoretically? 
I would have thought that a mixture model with:
\begin{align}
L( B, C | \theta_A ) &= 0.2 P( B | \theta_A ) + 0.8 P( C | \theta_A )
\end{align} 
would have been the way to go. 
I cannot find any references for their method, but I don't want to write it off just because I haven't ever seen it before.

I am aware of other ways to tackle the problem of information borrowing (for instance, treating A as missing data, or assuming a distribution in the parameters $\theta_A$, $\theta_B$, and $\theta_C$), but I am specifically wondering about the validity of this approach.

---

#### Example:

Let $A$ be the time-to-failure of a battery. We assume that $ A \sim \exp( \theta_A ) $, where $\theta_A$ is the rate of the exponential distribution. But we only observe $B$ from the distribution $\exp(\theta_B)$ and $C$ from the distribution exp($\theta_C$). We think battery A is 20% like B, and 80% like C. So the likelihood for $\theta_A$ using the method in question is:
$$
L( B, C | \theta_A ) = \theta_A e^{ \theta_A (B) (0.2) } \times  \theta_A e^{ \theta_A (C) (0.8) }
$$
Which we can maximise to find $\theta_A$.
Is this wrong?

Comment: It looks like it is related in form to a binomial distribution.

Comment: It does, but there are much more than two related events. My example shows A, B, and C, but they used A, B, C, ..., G. The weights still summed up to one. And they didn't make any binomial assumptions.

Comment: Multinomial, perhaps? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: It does resemble the likelihood, yes. But it is still a logic leap getting from the case presented to this "multinomial type likelihood", and my question is whether the logic makes sense. Therein lies the danger: the likelihood they use resembles some other likelihoods I have encountered. But does that make it correct, and does the approach have any validity?